# return a dataframe but got difference when using it in another function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to use a dataframe in `function_B`which is produced by function_A

```
def function_A():
   df = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['A'])
   return df

def function_B():
   df1 = function_A()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   function_A()
   function_B()
```

However, `df1` and `df` got difference.

`df` is like

```
    A
0   aaa

1   bbb
```

And `df1` is an EMPTY dataframe. Anyone knows the reason of it?

EDIT

I want to concatenate `df1` with another dataframe in `funtion_B`.

```
def function_B():
   df1 = function_A()
   df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data2,columns=['A'])
   pandas.concat([df1,df2])
```

Is there any other solutions except `return df1` which was referred by most of the answers.

Comment: You need to `return df1` in `function_B()`

Comment: Every time you call `function_B()` it defines `df1` by calling `function_A()`, i.e. it will create a new dataframe for each call of function B. You can use an existing dataframe by giving it as a parameter.

Comment: Your edit seems unclear. Can you provide what exact output you expect from the functions? Pinging @jpp because there might be another specific dupe target due to the recent edit.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r, Seen the edit, still very unclear. E.g. Why *not* return values. The question needs to explain the *problem* with using `return`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not empty. Just fix `function_B`:

```
def function_B():
    df1 = function_A()
    return df1
```

And of course `id(function_A())` and `id(function_B())` are not equal (e.g. dataframes are not the same object because you create a new `Dataframe` each time).

Comment: I want to concatenate df1 with another dataframe in funtion_B. Is there any other solutions except return df1. List in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to add a return to your function_b:

```
def function_B():
   df1 = function_A()
   return df1
```

Comment: I want to concatenate df1 with another dataframe in funtion_B. Is there any other solutions except return df1. See my edit